# Insert column if 2 column from different table matches

Tags: mysql, join, insert

I have 2 tables:

Table1- `contains PhoneNumber|Name`

Table2- `contains PhoneNumber|Address`

I want to create `Table3` with `PhoneNumber|Name|Address`

`Table1` and `Table2` may have out of order or different amount of entries, therefore table1 will act as main list.

please suggest way forward. using MySQL.

Comment: Check out `left join` clause and `insert ... select ...` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CREATE..SELECT` with a `LEFT JOIN` :

```
CREATE TABLE Table3 AS
SELECT t1.PhoneNumber,t1.name,t2.address
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
 ON(t1.PhoneNumber = t2.PhoneNumber)
```